Can be detected by google the 301 and 308?
I wanted to know if first the 301 and 308 are exactly the same and the second if Google can detect that there is a 301 or 308 done and could penalize the websites redirected.
I am trying to make a redirection to my padelshop für padelschläger kaufen and I wanted to know if it is okay to do.
I checked with other webiste and I don´t see clear if google can detect since the article is from a diferent thema.
